# PayPal SDK is not supported in .net core 6

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to integrate Paypal payment gateway in my project, But the SDK is available in nuget packages is not compatible with .Net 6. Its showing the error as below

"Package 'PayPal 1.9.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."

Do we have .net 6 support for this SDK?

Answer (score 1):

> Do we have .net 6 support for this SDK?

No, with the exception of the Braintree service *all* PayPal server-side SDKs are deprecated at the time of this writing. This includes the very old PayPal-NET-SDK and the newer Checkout-NET-SDK.

PayPal tells all new integrations to use direct HTTPS calls of first getting an access_token (which can be cached for 9 hours) and then doing w/e operation, which involves posting a JSON body and receiving a JSON response.

Useful references:

- PayPal REST Authentication: https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/authentication/
- The simplest full stack example, given in node.js (implement the backend with any environment): https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/